# Got a LogicException when enabling eAccelerator on Xampp

Tags: symfony, php, eaccelerator

If I tried to enable eAccelerator extesion in php.ini, the following error is show in Symfony 2. I use xampp 1.8.1.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your php.ini in [eaccelerator] section

```
eaccelerator.optimizer = "0"
```